# combine rows with identical index

Tags: python, pandas

How do I combine values from two rows with identical index and has no intersection in values?

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,None,None],[None,5,6]],index=['a','b','b'])
df

#input
    0   1   2
a   1.0 2.0 3.0
b   4.0 NaN NaN
b   NaN 5.0 6.0
```

Desired output

```py
    0   1   2
a   1.0 2.0 3.0
b   4.0 5.0 6.0
```

Comment: If there is more non NaNs values per same group what is expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please `stack()`, drops all nans and `unstack()`

```
df.stack().unstack()
```

Answer (score 1):

If possible simplify solution for first non missing values per index labels use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=0).first()
```

If possible same output from sample data is use sum per labels use `sum`:

```
df1 = df.sum(level=0)
```

---

If there is multiple non missing values per groups is necessary specify expected output, obviously is is more complicated.